# Use winexe to open windowed application remotely

Tags: windows, deployment, autohotkey, remote-access, winexe

I have to open an application like broffice on WINDOWS that is on AWS EC2 and write a text on it. This application is obviously windowed and I have to execute it from a Linux Server.
I'm trying to use winexe, but I think that it does not open windowed apps.
Is it possible to show windowed applications and performs clicks and writes tests on it remotely?
Please, do not worry about what I want to do after show window. I need run windowed applications remotely and show the window.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fix our problem creating a secure REST WS that receive a key and execute the command internally. It works in a queue of remote commands and return us the answer code. With this code we validate if our command was correctly executed or not. Other solutions found: use servlet, soap or queues, or virtualmanager. All those solutions was discarded because, or was very complicated for our problem or we don't have permission to execute, or will generate security problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could use winexe to call another tool that can handle the UI automation for you.  It looks like Autoit may be able to do what you need via creating a script and compiling  aut2exe.  https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: I have done it yet, and use autohotkey too, and other tools to automate. I run from remote Linux the command `winexe -U admin%admin //localhost "cmd /c path/script"` and, in this script, I've clicked on runProgram.exe. It did not work. I've tried autoitscript, autohotkey script, etc. I've tried to execute notepad.exe or explorer.exe instead script. And it didn't work too. I've tried to execute from Windows Scheculer some script and the same problem. I've tried to use verbose mode, and nothing.

Comment: The problem, I think, is that MS Windows cannot execute windowed applications out of context.

Comment: I don't know the context of what you are trying to do, but we have had to run automated UI tests in the past, and we were able to run a Jenkins executor on a windows VM without problem.  It would kick off selenium to do UI testing on the machine.

Comment: I have a solution using the virtualization layer. I got it executing command via vmware hypervisor. But I can do something more generic here.

Comment: was your Jenkins in Linux machine? Have the Windows machine some specific configuration? Do you remember it?

Comment: Our Jenkins master runs on Linux.  We no longer use a windows host to run the selenium tests.  I don't know if we had Jenkins running as a service or as a console application, otherwise nothing much was special.

Comment: I found a solution here and share with all of you. Thanks everybody.